# collection of objects to bytes format and then vice versa in java

Tags: java, collections, arrays

I have a collection of objects which i need to store in byte format and then afterwards i have to convert the data which in bytes back into collection of objects.I need the answer in java.
For eg I have an array of objects(any type) then i have to convert this array to byte array in java and then vice versa.

Please if possible suggest me the collection to use and the methods which support it.

Comment: Isn't this what serialization is for?

Comment: If you show us what you have, it will be easier to help you.  Have you googled 'java convert object to byte'?  It sounds like you want to serialize the object and send it over some means of communication, is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `Foo implements Serializable`, just do

```
List<Foo> list = createItSomehow();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);

try {
    oos.writeObject(list);
} finally {
    oos.close();
}

byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
// ...
```

And the other way round:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
List<Foo> list = null;

try {
    list = (List<Foo>) ois.readObject();
} finally {
    ois.close();
}

// ...
```

Instead of `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `ByteArrayInputStream` you can of course also supply `FileOutputStream` and `FileInputStream` respectively to write/read it to/from file.

#### See also:

- [The Java Tutorials - Essential Classes - Basic I/O - Object Streams](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html)